# Question on Integrability

Tags: real-analysis, integration, solution-verification

I am self-learning Real Analysis from the text *Understanding Analysis* by Stephen Abbott. I would like to ask, if my below proof/hypotheses is technically correct and rigorous. Do you have hint/clue (without revealing the entire proof)?

> **[Abbott 7.2.4]** Let $\displaystyle g$ be bounded on $\displaystyle [ a,b]$ and assume that there exists a partition $P$ with $\displaystyle L( g,P) =U( g,P)$. Describe $\displaystyle g$. Is $\displaystyle g$ necessarily continuous. Is it integrable? If so, what is the value of $\displaystyle \int _{a}^{b} g$?

***Proof***.

**Hypotheses.** If there exists a partition $\displaystyle P$, such that $\displaystyle L( g,P) =U( g,P)$ then it must be the case that $\displaystyle g$ can have at most a finite number of discontinuities and is constant or piecewise constant.

$\displaystyle g$ is not necessarily continuous. For example, let $\displaystyle g:[ 0,3]\rightarrow \mathbf{R}$ be defined as:

\begin{equation*}
g( x) =\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if } 0\leq x\leq 1\\
0 & \text{if} \ 1< x< 2\\
1 & \text{if } 2\leq x\leq 3
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}

Here, $\displaystyle L( g,P) =U( g,P)$. $\displaystyle g$ is integrable. Pick an arbitrary $\displaystyle \epsilon  >0$. Pick $\displaystyle P_{\epsilon } =P$. Then,

\begin{equation*}
U( g,P_{\epsilon }) -L( g,P_{\epsilon }) =U( g,P) -L( g,P) =0< \epsilon 
\end{equation*}

Since $\displaystyle \epsilon  >0$ is arbitrary, this is true for all $\displaystyle \epsilon  >0$. Consequently, $\displaystyle g$ is integrable.

Let $\displaystyle ( P_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty }$ be a sequence of partitions that are a refinement of $\displaystyle P$. Thus:

\begin{equation*}
P\subseteq P_{1} \subseteq P_{2} \subseteq \dotsc 
\end{equation*}

Since:

\begin{equation*}
L( f,P) \leq L( f,P_{n}) \leq U( f,P_{n}) \leq U( f,P)
\end{equation*}

and $\displaystyle L( f,P) =U( f,P)$ it follows that $\displaystyle L( f,P_{n}) =U( f,P_{n}) =L( f,P) =U( f,P)$. So,

\begin{equation*}
\lim ( U( f,P_{n}) -L( f,P_{n})) =0
\end{equation*}

By sequential criterion for integrability,

\begin{equation*}
\int _{a}^{b} g=\lim L( f,P_{n}) =L( f,P) =U( f,P)
\end{equation*}

Comment: To me, it is unclear what $L(g, P)$ and $U(g,P)$ are without reading the textbook. Is $L(g,P)=\sum_{\text{intervals $I$ in $P$}}\inf\{g(x)|x\in I\}$ and $U(g,P)$ something similar with $\sup$ instead of $\inf$?

Comment: I think you answered most of the question correctly, but the part "Describe $g$" is not complete: You only say: "$g$ can have at most a finite number of discontinuities" But are things like $g(x)=x$ or $g(x)=\mathrm{sgn}(x)$ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function, $\mathrm{sgn}(x)=0$ for $x=0$ and $\text{sgn}(x)=\pm1$ everywhere else) possible?

Comment: @student91, I guess yes, as long as we are considering a closed interval $[a,b]$ right?

Comment: Your interpretation of $L(g,P)$ and $U(g,P)$ is correct. They are the upper and lower Riemann sums with respect to the partition $P$.

Comment: I believe $g(x)=x$ certainly does _not_ have $L(g,P)=U(g,P)$ for any $P$. Let $[a,b)$ be an interval of the partition of $P$. Then $\inf\{g(x)|x\in[a,b)\}=a$ while $\sup\{g(x)|x\in[a,b)\}=b$, so $L(g,P)<U(g,P)$.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I think your example such as $g(x)=sgn(x)$ is a counterexample to my hypotheses. Maybe, I should add a further constraint, that the function should be atleast left- or right-continuous at these points.

Comment: If we accept the standard definition of lower and upper sums ie $U(f, P) =\sum_{k=1}^{n}M_k(x_k-x_{k-1})$ where $M_k=\sup\, \{f(x) \mid x\in [x_{k-1},x_k]\} $ then the function $g$ under consideration is constant on each subinterval of $P$ and hence is constant and its integral is equal to the value of any Riemann/Darboux sum. And you can now see that $g$ is obviously continuous.

Comment: Note that there is an alternative definition (given by H L Royden in his books) which uses $M_k=\sup\, \{f(x) \mid x\in(x_{k-1},x_k)\} $ and then your proof and conclusion is correct. In this case we call $g$ as a step function. So it will be great to add the exact definition of upper lower sums given by Abbott in your post.

Comment: Also if possible please fix the title of the question as currently it is too generic. For example you may write something related to "function with equal upper and lower Darboux sum"

Comment: To add, for other's reading this question - Abbott uses closed intervals in his definition of upper and lower sums.

Comment: @Quasar - please edit the question to include that information in it. People should not be forced to read the comments to get critical information about the problem. Also please fix the title as Paramanand has suggested. And though I suspect Paramanand's comments have answered the question for you, just to be clear your proffered example where $g$ is not continuous does not work. $x =1, x=2$ will always be in intervals where the maximum value of $g$ is $1$ and the minimum value of $g$ is $0$.